# SearchBar moving to default location on touch

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar`placed at the top of an `UIView`. When I click on a button, the `UISearchBar`is moving down.

My problem is that when I click on the `UISearchBar`, the element is moving to the original position (from when the view loads).

I have constraints to my `UISearchBar`, but nothing else.

[Here's a simple gist of my ViewController](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-besnard/1ba817a9c0ebaabeb542)